# Numba parallelization with prange is slower when used more threads

Tags: python, multithreading, numba

I tried a simple code to parallelize a loop with numba and prange. But for some reason when I use more threads instead of going faster it gets slower. Why is this happening? (cpu ryzen 7 2700x 8 cores 16 threads 3.7GHz)

```
from numba import njit, prange,set_num_threads,get_num_threads
@njit(parallel=True,fastmath=True)
def test1():
    x=np.empty((10,10))
    for i in prange(10):
        for j in range(10):
            x[i,j]=i+j
```

```
Number of threads : 1
897 ns ± 18.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 2
1.68 µs ± 262 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 3
2.4 µs ± 163 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 4
4.12 µs ± 294 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 5
4.62 µs ± 283 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 6
5.01 µs ± 145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 7
5.52 µs ± 194 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 8
4.85 µs ± 140 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 9
6.47 µs ± 348 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 10
6.88 µs ± 120 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 11
7.1 µs ± 154 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 12
7.47 µs ± 159 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 13
7.91 µs ± 160 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 14
9.04 µs ± 472 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 15
9.74 µs ± 581 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
Number of threads : 16
11 µs ± 967 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is totally normal. Numba needs to **create threads** and **distribute the work between them** so they can execute the computation in parallel. Numba can use different threading backends. The default if generally *OpenMP* and the default OpenMP implementation should be IOMP (OpenMP runtime of ICC/Clang) which try to *create threads only once*. Still, **sharing the work between threads is far slower than iterating over 100 values**. A modern mainstream processor should be able to execute the 2 nested loops in sequential in less than 0.1-0.2 us. Numba should also be able to **unroll the two loops**. The Numba function overhead is also generally about few hundreds of nanoseconds. The allocation of the Numpy array should be far slower than the actual loops. Additionally, there are other overheads causing this code to be significantly slower with multiple threads even if the previous overhead would be negligible. For example, **false-sharing** causes the writes to be mostly serialized and thus slower than if they would be done one 1 unique threads (because of a cache line bouncing effect operating on the LLC on x86-64 platforms).

Note that the time to create a thread is generally significantly more than 1 us because a system call is required.

Put it shortly: **use threads when the work to do is big enough and can be efficiently parallelized**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jérôme Richard. What do you mean by "can be efficiently parallelized"? With this code I want to do ''something'' 10 times. If I had to do it serial, it would take x time to do it. In parallel, with 10 thread for instance, theoretically it could be done 10 times faster (cause 10 iterations being done at the same time). Am I wrong?

Comment: With a serial code it will take a time `x` and in parallel a time `x/10+L` where `L` is the latency due to the multithreading, assuming you have at least 10 cores (10 threads on 1 core will not be faster than 1 thread for a computing task). The multithreading latency is the one to distribute the work between the threads and wait for them.

Comment: Here is an analogy: you need to buy 10 small/light objects in a shop where you are located. You can either do it yourself (serially) or call 9 friends to come to buy the 9 other objects for you and then give you the objects. Assuming your friends are not near, the time for you to do all the job alone is probably far smaller than the one to call each friend, to tell them what to do, for them to comes, and finally retrieve the objects ;) . If the objects are huge, then calling few friends is probably a good idea though. This is how multithreading works: *communication is slow*.

Comment: With 8 cores and 16 threads, will I gain faster time in parallel and with how many threads used? Furthermore, if I lighten the work per thread, will I see faster results?

Comment: In this case, it is better not to use multithreading. With a bigger work per threads, then threads start to be useful. The threshold is very dependent of your specific machine but you can consider multithreading useful for computation lasting >1 ms.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a case in which multithreading would be useful?

Comment: For example, matrix multiplications (though BLAS library used by Numpy does that job already well), or any mathematically intensive computation on large arrays like the computation of the Mandelbrot set, Fast-Fourier transforms, most image analysis (assuming the size is reasonable like 480p/720p/1080p), etc.